# Using custom navigation bar for different screen?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I'm developing an app which contains different `navigationBars`.

- Title & back button
- Title, left button & right button
- Title with notification icon with badge count
- Title with cart icon with badge count

In thought of 2 different approaches:

1. Create navigation in base controller `programmatically` (animation of badge icon for notification & card could be hard to animate?)
2. Create a custom `xibView`, which can be added as a subView to the navigation (could be hard to detect actions of buttons?)

What would be the better way to implement this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

The standard approach is to have a single **navigation controller**, that manages its navigation bar.

You don't interact with the navigation bar directly (or use a dettached navigation bar - this will bring you a lot of headaches regarding layout issues, etc. that `UINavigationController` takes care of for you, for free).

To change which buttons are visible on each screen, you modify each view controller's `navigationItem` property (its `leftBarButtonItem`, `rightBarButtonItem`, etc.).

[It's](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller) [all](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621851-navigationitem) [in](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationitem) [the](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationitem/1624946-leftbarbuttonitems) [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationitem/1624956-rightbarbuttonitems).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you create a custom xib.
Handling the actions: Let the handlers be in your custom class itself, you could define a protocol and use that to communicate the action event to any class which conforms to that protocol. 
The reason I would go with delegate is because we don't need many Controllers getting the event (Using Notifications), just the one class which currently conforms to that delegate.

Comment: But in this case all the controllers those have navigation bar need to have protocol implemented.For eg. mostly controllers have back button & title only so can i just create protocol for those controllers having left & right button.

Comment: I dont see that as a major issue, you can have default implementations for the protocol methods. That way you dont need to implement it in each view controller